# PHP If statement ->

Tags: php, json

Here is my problem

CODE:

```
$response = json_decode($data);

$arr = (array) $response;

if(is_array($arr['reviews'])){

foreach($arr['reviews'] as $review){

if ($review->rating == "0") {echo "<div class="0stars"></div>\n";}

}
```

It throws me an error when it gets to the `if` portions

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '0' (T_LNUMBER), expecting ',' or ';' in /home....
```

I've tried:

```
$reviewstar = $review->rating;
if ($reviewstar == "0") {echo "<div class="0stars"></div>\n";}
```

and many other options....

How can I do that? do I need to array again?

Thanks!

Comment: are you missing a closing parenthesis?

Comment: What error does it throw? There's no problem with your `if()` syntax, maybe the problem is that `$review` doesn't have a `rating` property?

Comment: "Throws me an error" without the error message is meaningless.

Comment: Instead of doing the array cast add true as the second parameter to json_decode.... `$response = json_decode($data, true);`

Comment: Sorry, for the miss explanation, what I want to do is when in the `foreach` I want to find out the value for the `rating` than if it matches the number 0 I want it to echo `<div class="0stars"></div>`

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '0' (T_LNUMBER), expecting ',' or ';' in /home....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes in this line are broken:

```
if ($review->rating == "0") {echo "<div class="0stars"></div>\n";}
```

Change it to:

```
if ($review->rating == "0") {echo "<div class=\"0stars\"></div>\n";}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast to array, but then use object type access here:

```
$review->rating
```

If you want to work with an array of objects the don't cast to an array (or force array in json_decode as has been suggested.

The most important thing is to understand the structure of the JSON string and how this will behave when decoded into an object/array.

Also it looks like you might not have closed out your curly braces from first `if` statement.

Comment: Ok here is how it goes json-> array only the "reviews"-> for each review there is a `rating` -> I want to replace the `rating` number in each `review` inside of the `foreach` with some html